# SQL Help in SELECT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table below with the following values:

```
Name            Type            
--------------------------------
Roger           A1
Roger           A2
Grace           A1
Grace           A2
Grace           A3
```

Now, I want to show only rows who are having A1 and A2, if there is A3 even if A1 and A2 is present under type, it will not show it.

The output shall be:

```
Name            Type            
--------------------------------
Roger           A1
Roger           A2
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please show your attempt query

Comment: What query did you try so far? What is the table name?

Comment: you can just name the table however you want.

Comment: i have tried exists, and sql in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query requirement is not very clear. But you can achieve your result from below query.

```
select * from table_3 
where name  not in (select name from table_3  group by name having count(distinct(type))=3)
```

Comment: We need to check whether A1, A2 is also present for the name. That check is missing in your query.

Comment: @VenkataramanR query edited. please check.

Comment: you guys are geniuses

Comment: we still need to ensure that names we select are still having A1,A2 in them. The query is not ensuring that. The query is based on sample data. But, the ask is, name with both A1, A2 and not A3.

Comment: @WirleyDaviondyllG.Valdez, if any of the answers, answers your query, please mark it as answer. It will be helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate count specifically for A1,A2 and calculate total count. Now, see if they are equal. Accordingly, pick up those names.

```sql
declare @table table(Name            varchar(20), Type            char(2))
insert into @table values
('Roger','A1'),
('Roger','A2'),
('Grace','A1'),
('Grace','A2'),
('Grace','A3');

;with NameCount
AS
(
select Name, count(case when type in ('A1','A2') then 1 END) AS SpecificCount, count(*) as totalcount from @table
group by name
)
SELECT t.* 
FROM @table as t
inner join NameCount as n
on n.Name = t.Name
where n.SpecificCount = n.totalcount
```

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Roger | A1 |
| Roger | A2 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do this **without a self-join**, by utilizing a conditional `COUNT` window function

```sql
SELECT t.Name, t.[Type]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN t.[Type] IN ('A1', 'A2') THEN 1 END)
                      OVER (PARTITION BY t.Name)
                = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Name)
        THEN 1 END AS OnlyA1OrA2
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE OnlyA1OrA2 = 1;
```